# Configure Apache to redirect all requests to index.html?

Tags: centos, configuration

A CentOS 7 server is hosting a web application in `/var/www/someapp/public_html`.  Requests for `mydomain.com` get served the file located at `/var/www/someapp/public_html/index.html`.  The user can then navigate to several browser-routes that are defined in the JavaScript web application.  However, when the user refreshes the browser from one of those UI-routes, apache replies with a message indicating that `the requested url is not found on the server`.

**What specific config settings need to be changed in order for all routes sent to apache to be redirected to `index.html`?**

Answer (score 2):

I do mine with a `.htaccess` file.  In the `DocumentRoot` for the site, I create the `.htaccess` file and it in goes

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Per @**StephenOstermiller** 's comment below, you also need to make sure that `AllowOverride All` is set in the Directory stanza as well.  While mine is set up that way, I forgot to add that in the post since it is part of my default config.... so @StephenOstermiller gets the credit for that part.

Comment: I created a `.htaccess` file in the `DocumentRoot` for the site in question, and put your exact syntax in it.  I then typed `systemctl restart httpd.service`, and I waited a couple minutes.  Then I reloaded the web site and refreshed one of the views, only to have the same problem persist.  What else do I need to change? Perhaps something else in `httpd.conf`?

Comment: You need to enable .htaccess by making sure that `AllowOverride All` is set for the directory in the Apache config files.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Your suggestion enabled this to work.  Therefore, if you write up an answer, I would be happy to mark it as accepted and +1.

Comment: You can mark this one.   It has the meat of it.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Meat alone gives people heart attacks, diabetes, and strokes.  Vegetables are required.  Your comments added the required vegetables.